# ERROR CON com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, webservice

Tengo una clase que recupera registros de mi base de datos por medio de web service y en el response llamo a un método que me crea un LinearLayout con la información recuperada por mi webservice, pero volley me dice que requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest), es null, este es mi web service

```
private void loadWebService() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String ip = getString(R.string.ip);
    String url = ip + "/firstTestSmb/wsConsultarList.php";

    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
    try{
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }catch (NullPointerException n){
        n.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("ERROR_NULL", n.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Notices notices = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("noticias");

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            notices = new Notices();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            notices.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
            notices.setTitulo(jsonObject.optString("titulo"));
            notices.setFecha(jsonObject.optString("fecha"));
            notices.setTexto(jsonObject.optString("texto"));
            notices.setUrl1(jsonObject.optString("url1"));
            notices.setUrl2(jsonObject.optString("url2"));
            notices.setUrl3(jsonObject.optString("url3"));
            notices.setUrl4(jsonObject.optString("url4"));
            notices.setUrl5(jsonObject.optString("url5"));
            notices.setUrl6(jsonObject.optString("url6"));
            listNotices.add(notices);
        }
        progressDialog.hide();
        addObject(listNotices);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        progressDialog.hide();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido establecer conexion con el servidor" + " " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("ERROR_ARRAY", response.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    progressDialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se Ha Podido Conectar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("ERROR_CONEXION", error.toString());
}

private void addObject(ArrayList datos) {

    List<Notices> list = datos;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card, null, false);

    nombre = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.nombre_opt_notices);
    fecha = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.fecha_opt_notices);
    titulo = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.titulo_opt_notices);
    texto = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.texto_opt_notices);

    nombre.setText(list.get(0).getNombre());
    fecha.setText(list.get(1).getFecha());
    titulo.setText(list.get(2).getTitulo());
    texto.setText(list.get(3).getTexto());

    layout.addView(linearLayout);
}
```

y mi archivo php que es el que realiza la conexion es este:

```
<?PHP

$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="db_test_first";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="";
$json=array();

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
    $consulta="select * from noticias";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["nombre"]=$registro['nombre'];
        $result["titulo"]=$registro['titulo'];
        $result["fecha"]=$registro['fecha'];
        $result["texto"]=$registro['texto'];
        $result["url1"]=$registro['url1'];
        $result["url2"]=$registro['url2'];
        $result["url3"]=$registro['url3'];
        $result["url4"]=$registro['url4'];
        $result["url5"]=$registro['url5'];
        $result["url6"]=$registro['url6'];
        $json['noticias'][]=$result;
        //echo $registro['id'].' - '.$registro['nombre'].'<br/>';
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Si ejecutas la dirección que hay en `url` directamente en el navegador te lanza un JSON válido, seguro? Copia y pega lo que lanza y valídalo usando `jsonlint.com` u otro validador en línea.

Comment: Tampoco entiendo de dónde sacaste tu código, por ejemplo aquí: `jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);` estás pasando `this` a los dos últimos parámetros, cuando esos dos últimos parámetros deberían ser el listener de la respuesta y el listener del error ([ver la clase](http://griosf.github.io/android-volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html)). ¿Por qué no implementas el código [como lo explica Android en la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request)?

Comment: No veo en tu código que tengas inicializado requestQueue, deberías de tener RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); antes de agregar algo.

Comment: FrEqDe tenias razon no habia inicializado el request muchas gracias

Comment: Perdón, [este es el enlace de referencia de la doc de Android para el tipo de petición que intentas hacer](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) (en el enlace de mi otro comentario es un ejemplo usando Singleton). Aunque el ejemplo de este enlace es un `StringRequest`, sólo tienes que cambiar eso por un `JsonObjectRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente tienes definida la variable:

```
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
```

pero no has inicializado el "queue" de solicitudes, esto lo debes realizar al iniciar tu Activity, Adapter, Servicio. Para esto es necesario el contexto:

```
// Create a Queue of requests
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```